# Can we cache yarn globals in github actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg, github-actions

I have some global packages such as serverless framework, ESLint and etc. I've implemented GitHub Actions cache for yarn. Below is my code.

```yaml
- uses: actions/cache@v1
  id: yarn-cache # use this to check for `cache-hit` (`steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'`)
  with:
    path: ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
    restore-keys: |
      ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-

- name: Adding serverless globally
  run: yarn global add serverless

- name: Yarn Install
  if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'              
  run: |
    echo "cache hit failed"
    yarn install
  env:
    CI: false
```

But my global packages are not cached. Is there any way to cache Yarn globals?

Comment: Why are you setting the `CI` environment variable to `false` in the "Yarn Install" step?

Comment: @Edric it's a mistake. I just copied my yarn build block and rename for Yarn Install.

Comment: Did you follow the [tutorial](https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/master/examples.md#node---yarn) to enable caching of yarn packages?

Comment: @smac89 yes I did. yarn cache works fine. Problem is with yarn global cache. and also after installing some yarn package as global, github actions fails to call it. So I'm currently using NPM for global installs. But still cache does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pasting the build file for the solution,

```
name: global-test
on:
    push:
        branches:
            - dev
    pull_request:
        branches:
            - dev
jobs:
    aws-deployment:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: CHECKOUT ACTION
              uses: actions/checkout@v2

            - name: NODE SETUP ACTION
              uses: actions/setup-node@v1
              with:
                  node-version: '12.x'

            - name: Get yarn cache directory path
              id: yarn-cache-dir-path
              run: |
                  echo "dir=$(yarn cache dir)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

            - name: Set yarn global bin path
              run: |
                  yarn config set prefix $(yarn cache dir)

            - name: Add yarn bin path to system path
              run: |
                  echo $(yarn global bin) >> $GITHUB_PATH

            - name: Set yarn global installation path
              run: |
                  yarn config set global-folder $(yarn cache dir)

            - name: CACHE ACTION
              uses: actions/cache@v2
              env:
                  cache-version: v1
              id: yarn-cache
              with:
                  path: |
                      ${{ steps.yarn-cache-dir-path.outputs.dir }}
                      **/node_modules
                  key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ env.cache-version }}-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
                  restore-keys: |
                      ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ env.cache-version }}-
                      ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-
                      ${{ runner.os }}-

            - name: Installing dependencies
              if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
              run: |
                  echo "YARN CACHE CHANGED"
                  yarn install

            - name: Adding serverless globally
              if: steps.yarn-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
              run: |
                  echo "NO CACHE HIT"
                  yarn global add serverless
```

I named the steps, so they can be understood.

UPDATED the answer on 2020-12-06

Comment: This throws: `The 'add-path' command is disabled. Please upgrade to using Environment Files or opt into unsecure command execution by setting the 'ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS' environment variable to 'true'. For more information see: github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands`